# How do I place my particles correctly?

Tags: particles

Are you speaking about Particle Settings or Particle Placement?

Before i hit render f12. All the bees stuck to the sphere. But after pressing f12 and render then i cancel it. And back to 3d view all the particles setting are disturb. May i know the reason whats going and why its not stuck same setting.

[image]

Any suggestion or Help. Thanks

**Bake**

[image]

Comment: Please improve your image.  Your gif is more of a problem for the reader than an explanation.  Please replace with a few images to improve the quality of you explanation.

Comment: Show your particle settings in one of your images and the timeline to see keyframes.

Comment: Please show the time line.

Comment: Please do the following.  Show an image and specify what meets your goal.  Show an image and specify what fails to meet your goal. .  Please tell me what is the mistake.  I do not know.

Comment: Please switch to images.  Your gifs are confusing.

Comment: IMHOIIHO ... The question is still not clear.  Partially due to the gifs which can be discarded 

Comment: It is still my opinion your gifs are of low quality. 

Comment: I still do not clearly see your particles setting in an image ... NOT a gif.

Comment: Please delete all your gifs.  Then show the sphere in wireframe mode.

Comment: What should your particles be doing? What is your goal?

Comment: Show the sphere in wireframe mode and use 8 particles for clarity of understanding.

Comment: Turn emitter off in particle settings then render and show image in question. NOT at some other site.

Comment: Show your camera view in a single image.

Comment: Please delete all gifs.

Comment: Show the render or no render for the particle system  in an image.   Show the render or no render for the particle emitter.

Comment: Try enable particles Rotation (set to normal-tangent), but w/o Dynamic

Comment: The question is still unclear

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have NOT turned off render of the particle emitter or particle system

[image]

- Turn Physics to None. Stop all animation of Bee.

---

- Stop your particle rotation.
- Perhaps your particles are rotating inside the sphere.
- Increase the particles.
- Move the frame cursor.
- Save your file.
- Close the file and open again.
- Blender particles can become out of synchronization.

Set keyframes for you particle settings if necessary.
Bake to cache.
Then render.

Comment: i tried it but i have attach a gif file in question plz check. All the setting change after bake

Comment: still did not work as the above steps mention.

Comment: particle setting and wireframe https://imgur.com/gallery/NKvEZJM